# Combine date column and time column into datetime column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, data-analysis

I have a Pandas dataframe like this; (obtained by parsing an excel file)

```
|     |     COMPANY NAME           | MEETING DATE        | MEETING TIME|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|YKSGR|    YAPI KREDİ SİGORTA A.Ş. | 2013-12-16 00:00:00 |14:00:00     |
|TRCAS|    TURCAS PETROL A.Ş.      | 2013-12-12 00:00:00 |13:30:00     |
```

Column `MEETING DATE` is a timestamp with a representation like `Timestamp('2013-12-20 00:00:00', tz=None)` and `MEETING TIME` is a `datetime.time` object with a representation like `datetime.time(14, 0)`

I want to combine `MEETING DATE` and `MEETING TIME` into one column. [datetime.combine](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) seems to do what I want, however, I need to apply this function column-wise somehow. How can I achieve this?

Comment: perhaps you could `apply` the function (or anyfunction you want) to MEETING DATE and MEETING TIME http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use apply method, and apply combine like this:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: combine(x['MEETING DATE'], x['MEETING TIME']), axis=1)
0   2013-12-16 14:00:00
1   2013-12-12 13:00:00
```

Comment: Hey I was stuck with a similar problem and I tried this - but I am getting an error - combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not Series.

I guess combine does not take the entire series, only one element at a time. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3):

Other solutions didn't work for me, so I came up with a workaround using `replace` instead of `combine`:

```
def combine_date_time(df, datecol, timecol):
   return df.apply(lambda row: row[datecol].replace(
      hour=row[timecol].hour,
      minute=row[timecol].minute),
      axis=1
   )
```

In your case:

```
combine_date_time(df, 'MEETING DATE', 'MEETING TIME')
```

It feels slow (I haven't timed it properly), **but it works**.

**UPDATE**: I have timed both approaches for a relatively large dataset (>500.000 rows), and they both have similar run times, but using `combine` is faster (59s for `replace` vs 50s for `combine`). Also, see [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42412926/2802352) answer on this.

**UPDATE2**: I have tried [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42412926/2802352)'s approach:

```
def combine_date_time(df, datecol, timecol):
    return pd.to_datetime(df[datecol].dt.date.astype(str)
                          + ' '
                          + df[timecol].astype(str))
```

This approach is blazing fast in comparison, [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42412926/2802352) is right. I haven't been able to measure it though, but it is evident.

Comment: I add faster solution, you can check it.

Comment: And how fast is my solution?

Comment: @jezrael sorry, I haven't been able to make it work. I cannot spend time on it right now. Thanks for the contribution, though.

Comment: no problem. in pandas is best use very fast pandas vectorized function and if does not exist, then use apply, because slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Time` column first to `string` and then [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then is easy sum both columns:

```
print (type(df['MEETING DATE'].iat[0]))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

print (type(df['MEETING TIME'].iat[0]))
<class 'datetime.time'>

print (df['MEETING DATE'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['MEETING TIME'].astype(str)))
YKSGR   2013-12-16 14:00:00
TRCAS   2013-12-12 13:30:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```