# datetime combine date & time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

Im trying to use this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009408/combine-date-column-and-time-column-into-datetime-column) to combine a date and time stamp but not having any luck..

```
#df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv')
```

This is where Im stuck, I don't know how to [import the package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) correctly..

This doesn't work:
`from datetime import combine`

```
df['DateTime'] = df.apply(lambda x: combine(df['Date'], df['Time']), axis=1)
```

When everything is all said and done, do I need to `parse_dates=True`? Usually all my data is a combined date time... and Finally I need to set a new index in my pandas data frame for the new combined date-time column.

Any tips greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: you can do `import datetime` and then use it like `datetime.datetime.combine` or `from datetime import datetime` and then `datetime.combine`

Comment: @Vaishali, thank you the answer in the link you provided 
totally worked... If you post an answer ill hit the green check. `df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the specified columns in datetime format using parse_dates parameter or read them as objects and then convert to datetime.

Option 1:

```
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
```

Option 2:

```
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
```

Comment: can you help me with this question by chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639490/attributeerror-int64index-object-has-no-attribute-month

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have data from which you want to make a date in column 1, then you use the magic formula:

```
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv',  parse_dates=[1])
```

Your method:

```
parse_dates = True
```

sometimes it does not work

If usually all yours data is a combined date and time you can use combine 3 columns by this formula:

```
df['date2']= pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
# to check
print(m1.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

function combine is inside the datetime type in datetime module.  Try this instead.

```
from datetime import datetime
df['DateTime'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(df['Date'], df['Time']), axis=1)
```

Comment: This raises an error: `TypeError: ('combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not Series', 'occurred at index 0')`