# AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'month'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I have some time series data with three separate colums (Date, Time, kW) that looks like this:

```
Date     Time        kW
3/1/2011 12:15:00 AM 171.36
3/1/2011 12:30:00 AM 181.44
3/1/2011 12:45:00 AM 175.68
3/1/2011 1:00:00 AM 180.00
3/1/2011 1:15:00 AM 175.68
```

And reading the csv file directly from Pandas I can parse the Date & Time:

```
df= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\master.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
```

Which appears to work nicely, but the problem is I want to create another data frame in Pandas to represent the numerical value of the month. If I do a:

```
df['month'] = df.index.month
```

An error is thrown:

`AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'month'`

I am also hoping to create additional dataframes to represent time stampt day, minute, hour... Any tips greatly appreciated..

Comment: Since Date is a column not an index, you need df.Date.dt.month

Comment: @Vaishali it's currently a string so they need to convert to a datetime before using the `.dt` accessor

Comment: Sorry not understanding all the way... :( Do I need to do anything different when importing from CSV?

Comment: @roganjosh, I believed the parse_dates in read_csv would have converted the date to datetime.

Comment: If you want them to be your index, use [`index_col`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @HenryHub, if the dtype of column date is datetime, the above code would work. Otherwise you would have to first convert it to datetime. Print df.dtypes to check

Comment: @Vaishali you might be right. I was just checking the regular `datetime` docs and apparently `%d` and `%m` can cope with non-zero-padded values so maybe it can guess the format in Pandas too

Comment: If I print `df_raw.dtypes` I get `Date_Time    datetime64[ns]` `kW                  float64` `dtype: object`

Comment: Henry, it seems like you're not really listening to the advice people are giving you. Have you tried `df['month'] = df.Date.dt.month` as suggested by @Vaishali ?

Comment: It would be df.Date_Time.dt.month

Comment: @Vaishali, would you know how I can create a df to represent time stamp hour.. And also another one to represent time stamp minute? `df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H')` gives me an attribute error `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: Also if you post an answer Ill hit the green check... This worked for month df, `df.Date_Time.dt.month`

Comment: Hour and minute will be represented as integer, not timestamp. df.Date_Time.dt.hour and df.Date_Time.dt.minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datetime accessor and extract month

```
df['month'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.month
```